# c++ vector not filling correctly

Tags: c++, vector

I'm making an engine that is supposed to read formatted text files and output them as a text based adventure. The world is being written into a vector matrix. However, my program only seems to fill the matrix in one Dimension and only with the information from the very first cell of the matrix.

The WorldReader reads the World file and returns a specified line:

```
std::string WorldReader(std::string file,int line)
{

    std::string out[n];
    int i = 0;
    World.open(file + "World.txt");
    if(!World.good())
        return "Bad File";
    else while(i<n && getline(World, out[i]))
    {
        i++;
    }
    World.close();
    return out[line];
}
```

Here is the write loop:

```
            for(j=0; j<(width*height); j++)
            {
                int x;
                int y;
                stringstream Coordx(WorldReader(loc, 4+j*10));
                Coordx >>  x;
                stringstream Coordy(WorldReader(loc, 5+j*10));              
                Coordy >>  y;
                std::string Desc = WorldReader(loc, 6+j*10);
                W1.writeCell(x,y,0,Desc);
            }
```

and here is the writeCell function:

```
    std::vector<std::string> Value;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > wH;
    std::vector< std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > > grid;

void World::writeCell(int writelocW, int writelocH, int ValLoc, std::string input)
{
    if (wH.size() > writelocH)
    {
        Value.insert(Value.begin()+ValLoc,1,input);
        wH.insert(wH.begin() + writelocH,1,Value);
        grid.insert(grid.begin() + writelocW,1,wH);
    }
    else
    {
        wH.insert(wH.begin(),1,Value);    
        grid.insert(grid.begin(),1,wH);
    }
}
```

also the matrix is getting immensely bloated even though i resized it to 3x3.

tips and help appreciated.

Comment: You've only provided snippets of the code, so it's kind of hard to tell what's going on here.  Try to create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: well i didn't want to make it to long, what else do you need to see?

Comment: You're right, don't post *more* code than this.  Instead, try to reduce your problem to a short, self-contained example that demonstrates the specific problem.  Then post that instead!

Comment: Make it both shorter and more complete.  Self contained, short, compiling.

Comment: edited it; is the problem comprehensible now?

Comment: Your problem is not related to reading from a file, to any 'World' class, etc. Try to make a program that can be compiled on its own and still exhibits the problem. Your question title mentions a vector, yet there is none to be found in your example code. More likely than not, reducing your test code to a minimal sample will lead you to the problem. And if it doesn't, well then people will at least be able to help you.

Comment: bringing it to a state where this part will run would make it at least twice as big, i don't want to do that sorry, i added the definition of the vectors in the writeCell snippets, hope it helps.

Comment: so the problem seems to be in the writeCell part, it writes into every cell of grid at the first [0] position of the subvector wH the full Value vector with the input of the first Cell, it is however supposed to write the correct Value in it's correct, specified cell

Comment: Somewhat related, is your world-reader specifically getting `n` from some global? Is the file *supposed* to be read in entirety or just to that magic value? Baby steps here. I'm trying to work through your code. Since you're only returning indexed line (`line`) is there some reason for not breaking this loop at that time, and honestly there is no need for the array at all. Elsewhere, the vector-of vector-of vector-of-string is giving me the creeps =P

Comment: n is just a const int and the whole worldReader is not optimized... but i don't think thats the problem, i think it's something about the writeCell... but i have been scratching my head for days at this and i can't figure it out... is there a better way to approach 3D vectors?

Comment: @user1931745 I don't think it is the problem either; I'm just digesting code over here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. I *think* I know where your problem is. Please note this is *extremely* difficult to analyze without genuinely-runnable code. The high-point is this: You're inserting a new 2D matrix *for every **value*** you process into your `grid`, and I hope it is clear why this is the case. It explains the mass-bloat (and inaccurate data) you're experiencing.

**Your original code**

```
void World::writeCell(int writelocW, int writelocH, int ValLoc, std::string input)
{
    if (wH.size() > writelocH)
    {
        // inserts "input" into the Value member.
        Value.insert(Value.begin()+ValLoc,1,input);

        // inserts a **copy** of Value into wH
        wH.insert(wH.begin() + writelocH,1,Value);

        // inserts a **copy** of wH into the grid.
        grid.insert(grid.begin() + writelocW,1,wH);
    }
    else
    {   // inserts a **copy** of Value into wH
        wH.insert(wH.begin(),1,Value);    

        // inserts a **copy** of wH into the grid.
        grid.insert(grid.begin(),1,wH);
    }
}
```

As you can plainly see. there is a whole lot of unintended copying going on here. You have three variables, each of which is independent.

```
std::vector<std::string> Value;
std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > wH;
std::vector< std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > > grid;
```

During the course of `writeCell` you are trying to insert your string into a 3D location, but only "dereferencing" to at-most one of those dimensions. And copies o-festival ensues

From your variable names I'm assuming your grid dimensionality is based on:

```
writeocW * writelocH * ValLoc
```

You need to unwind the dimensions in most-to-least significant order, starting with `grid`. ultimately that is how it is accessed anyway. I personally would use a sparse std::map<> series for this, as the space utilization would be *much* more efficient, but we're working with what you have. I'm writing this off-the-cuff with no nearby compiler to check for mistakes, so grant me a little latitude.

---

**Proposed Solution**

This is a stripped down version of the World class you no-doubt have. I've changed the names of the params to traditional 3D coords (x,y,z) in an effort to make it clear how to do what I *think* you want:

```
class World
{
public:
    typedef std::vector<std::string> ValueRow;
    typedef std::vector<ValueRow> ValueTable;
    typedef std::vector<ValueTable> ValueGrid;
    ValueGrid grid;

    // code omitted to get to your writeCell()

    void writeCell(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z, const std::string& val)
    {
        // resize grid to hold enough tables if we would
        //  otherwise be out of range.
        if (grid.size() < (x+1))
            grid.resize(x+1);

        // get referenced table, then do the same as above,
        //  this time making appropriate space for rows.
        ValueTable& table = grid[x];
        if (table.size() < (y+1))
            table.resize(y+1);

        // get referenced row, then once again, just as above
        //  make space if needed to reach the requested value
        ValueRow& row = table[y];
        if (row.size() < (z+1))
            row.resize(z+1);

        // and finally. store the value.
        row[z] = val;
    }
};
```

I think that will get you where you want. Note that using large coords can quickly grow this  cube.

---

**Alternate Solution**

Were it up to me I would use something like this:

```
typedef std::map<size_t, std::string> ValueMap;
typedef std::map<size_t, ValueMap> ValueRowMap;
typedef std::map<size_t, ValueRowMap> ValueGridMap;
ValueGridMap grid;
```

Since you'd be enumerating these when doing whatever it is you're doing with this grid, order of the keys (the 0-based indexes) is important, thus usage of `std::map` rather than `std::unordered_map`. An `std::map` has a *very* nice feature with its `operator[]()` accessor: *It adds the referenced key slot if it doesn't already exist*. Thus your writeCell function would collapse to this:

```
void writeCell(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z, const std::string& val)
{
    grid[x][y][z] = val;
}
```

Obviously this would radically alter the way you use the container, as you would have to be conscious of the "skipped" indexes you're not using, and you would detect this while enumerating with the appropriate iterator for the dimension(s) being used. Regardless, your storage would be *much* more efficient.

Anyway, I hope this helps at least a little.

Comment: @user1931745 Don't forget, accessing a map through operator[] will default construct the item in the indexed location, so you should be using **iterators** to walk your maps; not for-index-loops. Otherwise you may as well use the first solution. I hope I made that clear. Very glad  to help!